# Make boolean values editable in list_display Wagtail?

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I want to edit boolean values from the list page in Wagtail Admin. I cant seam to get this functionality working in Wagtail as its built upon Django i believe it can work on Wagtail as well but i cant figure it out.

Django way of doing it:

```
class TaskAdmin(models.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (..., 'boolean_field')
    list_editable = ('boolean_field',)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to add site settings to the Wagtail admin. Is this what you're looking for? You can make boolean toggle switches in the settings menu and then pass the values to a view or a template. It would look something like this:

```
from django.db import models
from wagtail.contrib.settings.models import BaseSetting, register_setting

@register_setting
class TaskAdmin(BaseSetting):
    list_display = models.BooleanField()
    list_editable = models.BooleanField()
```

Docs are here: https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/contrib/settings.html